# How can I determine what is causing an unwanted package to be built in Yocto?

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I am trying to build an console image for an RPi using the `core-image-base` recipe, but somewhere in my configuration, I seem to have switched something on that is increasing the number of recipes built by around 1000 which include many things that don't feel like they belong in a console image (`libx11`, `gnome-desktop-testing`, etc.)

I am trying to track down why these recipes are being included in my build. My method so far has been to run the following commands:

```sh
# Generate a massive dot file with all the dependencies in it
bitbake -g core-image-base

# grep through that file to find out what is bringing in
# gnome-desktop-testing.
cat task-depends.dot | grep -i gnome-desktop-testing | grep -vi do_package_write_rpm
```

I removed `do_package_write_rpm` from the matching since everything seems to match against it. This leaves the following:

```
"core-image-base.do_build" -> "gnome-desktop-testing.do_build"
"core-image-base.do_rootfs" -> "gnome-desktop-testing.do_package_qa"
"core-image-base.do_rootfs" -> "gnome-desktop-testing.do_packagedata"
"core-image-base.do_rootfs" -> "gnome-desktop-testing.do_populate_lic"
"glib-2.0.do_package_qa" -> "gnome-desktop-testing.do_packagedata"
(followed by many dependencies between the tasks of the gnome-desktop-testing recipe)
```

So, if my interpretation is correct, it seems that `core-image-base` is depending directly on `gnome-desktop-testing`. This seems unusual since `core-image-base` is supposed to be a console only image.

I tried adding `PACKAGE_EXCLUDE = "gnome-desktop-testing"` to my local.conf hoping that it would give back some more information, but the build just seems to proceed regardless of this variable's setting :/

How can I figure out why `gnome-desktop-testing` is being built by Yocto? Ideally I would like to have a solution not involving toaster.

Comment: It's easier to check the dot files in the buildhistory directory to find this.  With bitbake -g you see the yocto steps.  In the buildhistory only the packages.  To have this directory, you have to add 'INHERIT += "buildhistory"' and  'BUILDHISTORY_COMMIT = "1"'.  @see https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#ref-classes-buildhistory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this issue and so I thought I would post the answer.

First, I removed the recipe, rebuilt and then looked at the first dependency chain.

```
NOTE: Runtime target 'shared-mime-info' is unbuildable, removing...
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['shared-mime-info', 'glib-2.0', 'gnome-desktop-testing']
```

Then we look in the recipe to see that glib-ptest has an RDEPENDS on gnome-desktop-testing.

```
RDEPENDS_${PN}-ptest += "\
            coreutils \
            libgcc \
            dbus \
            gnome-desktop-testing \
            tzdata \
```

So then to fix that you will need to disable "ptest". This can be done from the your distro configuration (`meta-layer/conf/distro/*.conf`).

Answer (score 0):

One brutal solution to this problem is to just delete the recipe that you don't want and to rerun bitbake. This gives you a useful message such as:

```
ERROR: Required build target 'core-image-base' has no buildable providers.
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was:
['core-image-base', 'packagegroup-base-extended', 'ofono', 'glib-2.0', 'gnome-desktop-testing']
```

If you have brought in these layers using git, the changes can be quickly reverted with `git checkout path/to/deleted/recipe`

Comment: `PACKAGE_EXCLUDE` should have the same behavior AFAIU and it's a bit "cleaner" than straight up deleting a recipe (especially since you can have multiple versions of the "same" recipe in different layers.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I did try with `PACKAGE_EXCLUDE = gnome-desktop-testing` in local.conf but it didn't seem to make a difference...

Comment: Two possibilities: 1) this recipe is being used for building another recipe but its packages never makes it to your final image, 2) the packages being installed aren't named `gnome-desktop-testing` but something slightly different. In the end, your radical solution worked better in your case :)

Comment: I suspect #2 is the reason, I was thinking perhaps the package is called something like `gnome-desktop-testing-dev` or `gnome-desktop-testing-bin`.